# How to display widgets inside a page content without a plugin?

Tags: categories, widgets, post-content

I want to build a homepage where I can show posts gathered from different categories and having the ability to choose such categories from the admin. I was thinking to use widgets for this. Is the right choice or is there a better way to do it?

I've found this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-shortcode-any-widget/) which seems to do what I need, but if possible I would prefer avoiding the use of a plugin.

Comment: You can do this in several ways, you can weather create a dedicated template that would suit your needs. You could declare dynamic sidebar zones and use widgets or directly get your desired posts with some WP_Queries

Comment: I don't want to show the posts in a sidebar, but in the content of the page. Can I declare a dynamic zone in there? And I know about WP_Queries, but how can I control them from the admin panel?

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks, that is interesting, but if I understood it correctly, it's not really what I meant

Comment: I can maybe try it later, but it seems he's tying a single category to a specific page, using one common page template. I want to show several categories in a single page

Comment: I've done something very similar here http://ottawacitizen.com/ with a back end that lets you select multiple lists from multiple sources including external feeds. If you want to this far in, get ready to do a lot of coding or download a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to register dynamic zones, you can follow theses steps :

- Create a template for your home page
- Assign that template to a page
- Define that page as the Home page in Settings->reading
- Register sidebar in your functions.php by using [this function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)
- Call the sidebar in your home template

In order to call your sidebar, use [dynamic_sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar). So if you named your sidebar with the id "home-sidebar-1", you can call it this way :

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('home-sidebar-1') ?>
```

You can add as many sidebar as you have declared in your functions.php

Comment: so, just to be sure: even if the function is called dynamic_sidebar, I can use it also for the main content, not just in a sidebar, right?

Comment: Yes, you can call dynamic_sidebar anywhere you want. The zones will be editables in apparence->widgets.

But you can't call dynamic_sidebar in the wysiwyg editor

Comment: that's fine. This is exactly what I needed